# Backup Master process fails to start -- HBase 1.0.1

Tags: hbase

I am configuring HBase 1.0.1.1 in fully distributed mode over 3 nodes. Node-1 should run the Master server, zookeeper & regionserver; Node-2 should run zookeeper & regionserver; Node-3 should run Backup Master, zookeeper & regionserver. I am facing two issues with the setup and need your help — 1) when I run start-hbase.sh I can see that “HMaster” is running on Node-1; “HRegionServer” is running on both Node-2 & Node-3; “HQuorumPeer” is running on all the 3 Nodes. But the Backup Master process failed to start on Node-2…. Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use 2) The second problem is, after running stop-hbase.sh the “HQuorumPeer” process continue to run on all the 3 nodes. They are not stopped by the stop-hbase.sh script.

Can you please help?

Regards, Gautam

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu, check this problem http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#loopback.ip

And check log files ( $HBASE_HOME/logs/hbase-hadoop-regionserver-{your_host}.log )

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the first problem is port conflict. You either have started the backup master already on node-2 or you have someother process running on the port which hbase-master(backup) is trying to comeup on.I think the port for hbase master in newer version is 16010. so identify it and kill it.
And also you need to have the backup master hostname in the backup-masters file under the conf folder.

Second problem: Zookeeper has failed to stop. so you can manually kill them using kill command.